# MOQ Mock void method that changes a field value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am new to MOQ and Mocking.
Assume I have a class like this, with a void method that changes a value:

```
public class Sample
{
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }

    public virtual void Check(int a)
    {
        this.Number = a > 10 ? this.Number = 100 : this.Number = 200;
    }
}
```

I want to test the void method to make sure it is changing the local field `Number`.

```
[Fact]
public void TestSampleClass()
{
    var sut = new Mock<Sample>();
    sut.Setup(s => s.Number).Returns(50);           

    sut.Setup(s => s.Check(It.IsAny<int>())).Callback(
        (int testNumber) =>
        {
            if (testNumber > 10)
            {
                sut.Setup(s => s.Number).Returns(100);
            }
            else
            {
                sut.Setup(s => s.Number).Returns(200);
            }                   
        });
}
```

It seems that the method doesn't change the value to 100 or 200... 
If I print `sut.Object.Number` it gives the initial value, not the updated one after void call.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I noticed `this.Number = a > 10 ? this.Number = 100 : this.Number = 200;` which can be shortened to `this.Number = a > 10 ? 100 : 200;`.

Comment: I don't really see a need for mocking this class, this looks to be completely testable without the use of mocking

Comment: Yes @Kritner this is easily Testable without mocking. But my Original class is too complicated to fit here. I wanted to simplify my problem find a helloworld solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless your example is a simplified representation of a much more complicated problem, there is no need to mock the `Sample` class.

```
[Fact]
public void TestSampleClass()
{
    //Arrange
    var testNumber = 5; //Could be what ever number you want to test
    var expected = 200
    var sut = new Sample();

    //Act
    sut.Check(testNumber);
    var actual = sut.Number;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

If the intention was to learn how to perform such a test in this particular situation then you can do something like this...

Assuming you wanted to test that the `Check` method on the following interface...

```
public interface ISample {
    int Number { get; set; }
    void Check(int a);
}
```

where the expected behavior is to have the method change the value of a property using `Moq` then this is how you can set it up.

```
[Fact]
public void TestISampleCheck() {
    //Arrange
    var testNumber = 5; //Could be what ever number you want to test
    var expected = 200;
    var mock = new Mock<ISample>();

    //Specifies that the all properties on the mock should have "property behavior",
    //meaning that setting its value will cause it to be saved and later returned
    //when the property is requested. (this is also known as "stubbing"). The default
    //value for each property will be the one generated as specified by the Moq.Mock.DefaultValue
    //property for the mock.
    mock.SetupAllProperties();

    var sut = mock.Object;

    mock.Setup(s => s.Check(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Callback((int a) => {
            if (a > 10) {
                sut.Number = 100;
            } else {
                sut.Number = 200;
            }
        });

    //Act
    sut.Check(testNumber);
    var actual = sut.Number;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it a lot @Nkosi.  Your description was really helpful. I was not sure why my value are always Moq.Mock.DefaultValue. 

I did not know about stubbing :). 

Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Callback` method just sets the behavior of the method, to make some changes you actually need to call mocked method i.e. `sut.Object.Check(11);`, then you can assert your results.

Comment: That is not working becuase as Nkosi addressed sut.Object.Check(11); shows Moq.Mock.DefaultValue. I should have used stubbing