# How to change Moq Object value when an event is raised

Tags: c#, moq

I have a Mock object `ttLoc` for `ILocation`.I have set its State value as `LocationState.Available`.
I have a method called `UpdateLocationState` which will update the State for which I am writing the test case.
When the State is updated an event is raised.

When the event is raised I want to update `ttLoc.Object.State` to `LocationState.Reserved`.
How can I achieve this?

```
var ttLoc = new Mock<ILocation>();
ttLoc.Setup(loc => loc.LocationId).Returns("TestLocation");
ttLoc.Setup(state => state.State).Returns(LocationState.Available);

this.ManagerMock.Setup(d => d.SetLocationState(It.IsAny<ILocation>(), It.IsAny<LocationState>())).Raises(f => f.LocationStateChangedEvent += null, new EventArgs<LocationState>(LocationState.Available));

var result = LocationService.UpdateLocationState(ttLoc.Object, LocationState.Reserved);
```

Comment: have tried this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286783/how-do-i-raise-an-event-when-a-method-is-called-using-moq

Comment: provide a [mcve] that can be used to properly understand the issue. Show the method under test, how it interacts with the mock, and the desired behavior. It is currently not entirely clear what the code is trying to do.

Comment: @Nkosi my problem is almost similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761339/moq-mock-void-method-that-changes-a-field-value   Here my problem is I cannot create mock for LocationService to set up the data

Comment: @reddy understood but you will have to show the definitions of `ILocation` and the parts of `LocationService` and `UpdateLocationState` so that we can show you what you need to do. Right now one only guess how they interact.

Comment: @Nkosi my problem is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761339/moq-mock-void-method-that-changes-a-field-value only difference is Sample.Number is read only property that is it has only Get property so when I assign value it says read only property.Can you please help me how to mock read only peroperty here?

Comment: @reddy I told you that i get that your problem is similar. I however cannot help you If I do not have an understanding of your specific situation though similar. Your current example does not provide enough context. which is why I asked for more information. With what you currently have my only suggestion would be to use a function in the Returns of the State setup but again, there is not enough info in your question for me to be confident that that is the answer, which is why I have not provided one.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do this with the SetupAllProperties() function. see:
[How to assign values to properties in moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816551/how-to-assign-values-to-properties-in-moq)

You could then just assign the new state to the moq object property.